# mongodb: how to update multiple fields in a nested array item of a single document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[
  {
    _id: "...",
    title: "some title",
    tasks: [
      { 
        id: "...",
        field1: "abc",
        field2: "def"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I would like to modify both field1 and field2 for a given task. I see lots of examples of how to update a single field, but not multiple fields.

I've tried the following, but it's simply replacing the whole task object with only the fields I'm setting.

```
    let changes = { field1: "123", field2: "456" };

    db.collection("lists")
        .updateOne(
            {   
                "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.listId), 
                "tasks.id": req.params.id 
            },
            { $set: { "tasks.$": changes } }
        );
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

#### WORKING SOLUTION

```
    let changes = { field1: "123", field2: "456" };
    Object.keys(changes).forEach(key => {
        changes[`tasks.$.${key}`] = changes[key];
        delete changes[key];
    });
    db.collection("lists")
        .updateOne(
            {   
                "_id": new ObjectId(req.params.listId), 
                "tasks.id": req.params.id 
            },
            { $set: changes }
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to follow query something similar like below to update the nested document inside an array. You have to give separate names for `field1` and `field2`.Here is the [document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) link

```
 db.collection.updateOne(
               {"_id": new ObjectId(req.params.listId),"tasks.id": req.params.id },
               { $set: { "tasks.$.field1":"xyz","tasks.$.field2":"mno" } } )
```